# Relations with TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Earlier i used Symfony 1.4. Now i learn Symfony 2. I do: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
    and i have:

```
    class Product
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    //...
}
```

and

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    //...
}
```

In Symfony 1.4 in foreach i can used:

```
    $result = findAll from Products.
foreach ($results as $result){
    echo $result->getCategory()->getName();
}
```

How can i get relations (in this example Category) with TWIG system?

```
{% for item in results %}
                <li><a href="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }} --- {{ item.category }} {{item.category.name}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
```

item.category and item.category.name doesnt working. I can't find this in documentation.

**EDIT:**

OK, i know now. I dont have relation in one product. How can i protected before this?

i have:

```
id | name    | category
1  | first   | 1
2  | second  | NULL
3  | third   | 2
```

if in each row category is not null then this working OK, but if i have NULL in relations then i have error:

```
Item "name" for "" does not exist in AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 3
```

What i can make with this?

Comment: It seems, that there is something broken with your relationship. I have something similar and there `{{ article.user.name }}` works fine.

Comment: Which example? I just wanted to tell, that your `{{item.category.name}}` _should_ work and I guess, that your problem must be somewhere earlier

Comment: i get this example from documentation. I would like learn relations from other example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to where you want to output the name. This will prevent twig from throwing that error.

```
{% if item.category.name is defined %}
    {# print the name here #}
{% endif %}
```